# Converting SQL2008 RDL file to SQL2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

How do I convert a RDL file that was created using the SQL2008 designer to work on SQL2005 Reporting services?

Comment: I suppose it would be possible if you had the schemas for both rdl versions and then doing a transform. Not to be pessimistic, but I've never seen those and I would doubt M$ has made them public.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no specific downgrade path see this [link](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=350119) for the official MS statement.

If you're feeling adventurous (and lucky) you could try converting your 2008 RDL to match the 2005 but I'm guessing that would be a major undertaking. RDL files are simply xml files that conform to the RDL spec which is open and published by Microsoft.

The RDL spec for reporting services 2008 is available here:

http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/5/7/6575f1c8-4607-48d2-941d-c69622e11c32/RDL_spec_08.pdf

The spec for 2005 is available here:

http://download.microsoft.com/download/c/2/0/c2091a26-d7bf-4464-8535-dbc31fb45d3c/rdlNov05.pdf

Comment: In the end it was less hassle to just redo the work in the 2005 designer

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue.  Thought that a 2008 server was about to be deployed and developed for that.  My "conversion" method:  Use the 2005 wizard to make the most primitive of reports, then put 2008 and 2005 side-by-side and copy stuff.  Using RDP with two monitors, so I can actually cut-n-paste epressions, format strings, properties, etc.