# can i run my reports developed in using ssrs 2008 on ssrs 2000

Tags: reporting-services

can i run my reports developed in using ssrs 2008 on ssrs 2000

Comment: are you sure you didn't mean ssrs 2010 instead of ssrs 2000?

Comment: There is no such thing as ssrs2010. Right now 2008 R2 is the latest.

Answer (score 3):

No.  No you can not.

Comment: Is this from experience, from research, or just an educated 'it certainly can't be possible' guess?  Whichever way, +1 from me.  BTW - can I use ROW_NUMBER() on SQL Server 6 if I restore a SQL Server 2008 R2 database onto it?  :D

Comment: The file formats and feature sets are completely different.  Have I tried it?  No.  Because I know it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

To get 2005 reports to run in 2000 was just a question of stripping out a couple of lines, but 2008 is different so this does not appear possible.

See this [Converting SQL2008 RDL file to SQL2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097690/converting-sql2008-rdl-file-to-sql2005)

Not quite a duplicate as you want to run on 2000 and not 2005.