# Convert SSRS 2008 Templates to SSRS 2005

Tags: reporting-services

Does anyone know how to convert a template created in SSRS 2008 to be deployed to SSRS 2005 Server?

Comment: Good luck.  Does not sound fun.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot run a 2008 report on a 2005 server.  I have heard that there are tools that exist to do the conversion, though.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097690/converting-sql2008-rdl-file-to-sql2005).

Answer (score 1):

You can't convert SSRS 2008 to 2005 as it is not backward compatible. There are tools available but those are also not able to convert with 100% accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just uploading the RDL to your 2005 server? The RDL is just an xml file so if you're lucky 2005 server can read and execute the file normally- or perhaps any errors you may get will help you find out what you need to do.

I recently converted 2005 RDLs to 2008, and if i look at the DIFF between the two files it's rather large, so dont get your hopes up :(

Otherwise I have no experience with this.

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but SSRS 2008 has some keywords that SSRS 2005 don't recognize. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try converting 2008 RDL to 2005 RDL. You can find the specs in the following links:
The RDL spec for reporting services 2008 is available here:

http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/5/7/6575f1c8-4607-48d2-941d-c69622e11c32/RDL_spec_08.pdf

The spec for 2005 is available here:

http://download.microsoft.com/download/c/2/0/c2091a26-d7bf-4464-8535-dbc31fb45d3c/rdlNov05.pdf

Answer (score -1):

Open your report in notepad and then change XML header.Replace 2008 with 2005.

Comment: Sagar, the issue with this is that the XML format will have tags that are supported into 2008, but not in 2005. You cannot do a straight conversion this way.